# Wrapping functions

Tags: swift, function, generics, types, rtti

In swift functions do not provide regular functionality of nominal types. Meaning that the only solution is to wrap them into some object. In `struct`, for example:

```swift
struct Functor<Input, Output> {
    //assuming only fuctions with one argument
    let function: (Input) -> Output
    let inputType: Input.Type
    let outputType: Output.Type
    let input: Input
    let output: Output

    init<Input, Output>(_ function: @escaping (Input) -> Output) {
        self.function = function //there is already a compilation error
        self.input = Input //???? And I have not a clue on how to store argument as instance
    }
}
```

Compiler says that:

```
error: cannot assign value of type '(Input) -> Output' to type '(Input) -> Output'
```

Is there a way to make it possible, or is it unimplementable due to type system design flaw?

Comment: @Chris Uhm, I am not sure i understand to what code you do refer. The example in op is complete. I guess, you mean this ```let a = Functor<Int, Int>.init { a in a + 1 }```. Even if we distill original example to this ```struct Functor<Input, Output> {
    //assuming only fuctions with one argument
    let function: (Input) -> Output

    init<Input, Output>(_ function: @escaping (Input) -> Output) {
        self.function = function //there is already a compilation error
    }
}

let myLovelyFunction = Functor<Int, Int>.init { a in return a + 1 }
 ``` it still produces error

Comment: yep my mistake - sorry! Not paying enough attention to the context.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a generic method inside a generic type, the inner generic parameters (on the method) shadow the outer generic parameters.

You should not make your initializer generic:

```
struct Functor<Input, Output> {
    //assuming only fuctions with one argument
    let function: (Input) -> Output
    let inputType: Input.Type
    let outputType: Output.Type
    //### I do not understand how you want to use the followings...
//    let input: Input
//    let output: Output

    init(_ function: @escaping (Input) -> Output) { //### Do not put inner generic parameters
        self.function = function
        //### I do not understand how you want to use the followings...
        self.inputType = Input.self
        self.outputType = Output.self
    }
}
```

I do not understand what you really want to do with the line of the second error, so please add a comment or update your question to clarify that.

Comment: I want to add following procedures ```    func hasSignature(identicalTo another: Self) -> Bool
    //(...)
    func hasArgumentSignature(identicalTo another: Self) -> Bool
    func hasSameReturnType(as another: Self) -> Bool ```

Comment: what i want come in the end is ```postconditions``` and ```preconditions``` like in D lang. To check if input and output satisfy given predicate. This is what i believe can be eventually come with this ```@CustomStorage(constarints: [{ $0 is Numeric }]) var someNumber: Any = 5; try? assign(value: 0.5, to: someNumber)```

Comment: @oneWayTicket, you should better add all that requirements in your post. The generic type would not work as you expect. `Self` is fully equivalent to the specialized type. When `fn` is a `Functor<Int, Int>`, `hasSignature(identicalTo:` accepts only `(Int)->Int`. Swift is not D, and the ways of handling dynamic types differs in languages. You may need to re-design your strategy to achieve what you really want to do. Update your question and include the description of what you really want to do, and someone can show you how Swifty design would be.

Comment: Ok, i will. Thank you for response.